# WordPress Unyson - Share page options

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the unyson Framework for WordPress and currently using page options which work just fine on that particular page.

But I want to be able to access those options when on another page.

Here is my php -

```
$page = fw()->theme->get_options( 'service-settings' );
<?php echo wp_kses_post($page['service']['options']['service-box']['options']['description']; ?>
```

But this doesn't allow me the content from the array.

Using the following I can see the array, but cannot get the data.

```
fw_print($page);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving *just* options array by calling `fw()->theme->get_options('slug')` - literally what you typed in the `framework-customizations/theme/options/slug.php` file.

If you want to receive the actual data you need to use [DB helpers](http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/helpers/php.html#database).

```
$data = fw_get_db_settings_option();

// or even refer to individual options, for performance's sake
$individual_option = fw_get_db_settings_option('option_id');

fw_print($data);
fw_print($individual_option);
```